Zip code validation to exclude some formats
I am trying to find a "correct" US ZIP code validation but can't. All of them suggesting some version of 5 digits, optionally followed by a dash and 4 digits. In its simplest form:
(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)

This and all of its variations pass "invalid" ZIP codes 00000 and 00000-0000. US Postal ZIP can potentially start with 2 zeros (00501 - Holtsville, New York) but not more than two zeros.
I need help modifying the above expression to exclude 000dd and 000dd-dddd. Last 4 can be all zeros, not important.
So, 00000, 0000d, 000dd should fail.

Do you have to do it in the same regexp? Why not use two rules -- one that matches potential zip codes, then another that filters out these exceptions?

true, misread the pattern.

Less than half of the possible ZIP codes are actually in use.  Eliminating those with three leading zeros is a completely negligible part of the task of ZIP code validation.  You're going to need to do some sort of table/database lookup anyway, which would automatically handle these cases.

To put this in context, an Oracle stored procedure needs to go through zip codes send by foreign post offices and they sometimes royally mess it up. This SP needs to be able to convert these invalid postcodes to valid ZIP codes. (e.g., convert "IL60630" to "60630" or "NEW HAMPS" that cannot be salvaged). As first step, if it encounter a "valid" 5 or 5-plus-4 postcode, it need not go through any other checks. I am trying to exclude 00000 or 00012.

@Barmar are you saying to use the existing regex to catch the 5 or 5-dash-4 matches and if found then check if it starts with 3 or more zeros?

zipcode REGEX_LIKE '...' AND zipcode NOT LIKE '000%'

First, you can factor your existing regular expression so that the first 5 digits are stated once, and the last 4 digits are stated as an optional group, like this:
^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$

One way to exclude anything beginning with three "0" is to insert a negative lookahead assertion:
^(?!000)\d{5}(-\d{4})?$

Another way that is purer (from a computer science theoretical framework), but more verbose, is to manually enumerate what happens if the first N digits are "0":
^([1-9]\d{4}|0[1-9]\d{3}|00[1-9]\d{2})(-\d{4})?$


Thank you, I tested it in Regex101 and works as intended,
